# libeigen-dev conflicts with OS version of package

Tags: ros, package, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When attempting to install electric, I've come across a conflict with the Ubuntu repository package for libeigen3-dev:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-electric-eigen: Depends: libeigen3-dev (= 3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid) but 3.0.2-ubuntu2~lucid is to be installed
```

I can force libeigen3-dev to electric's version, but this does not feel like the "correct" option.

Is this a known issue? There is a similar question here:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/2094/problem-while-installing

... but it only discusses a work-around and not the base issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11317/libeigen-dev-conflicts-with-os-version-of-package./) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Up until Ubuntu 11.04, Eigen3 is not part of the official Ubuntu repository, so the problem is most likely due to a conflicting version in another third-party repository. I suggest to force the ROS version for now.

For a long-term solution, it seems to me that `ros-electric-eigen` depending on a very specific version of libeigen3-dev is way too strict. If the package dependency were modified to e.g. `Depends: libeigen3-dev (>= 3.0.1)`, the whole issue would resolve. This will become more urgent when Ubuntu 11.10 introduces its own version of libeigen3-dev (3.0.1-1).

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-09-27**:
If you backported from 11.10, ABI breakage is unlikely. By the way, the backport version number 3.0.1-1+ros4 is greater than the original 3.0.1-1, which will prevent it from being updated on a system upgrade. If you use ~ instead of +, the upgrade works as expected.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-27**:
The specific version is necessary in order to not cause ABI compatibility issues with these backport libs -- we lock to the version our debs were built against so that we can produce errors (like above), when there's a chance that two debs are built against different ABIs.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-02-16**:
Additionally, if one adds the ppa for PCL in order to use PCL outside of ROS, its version of libeigen3-dev is (3.0.x-1+lucid1) and is incompatible with the debian requirements for any ROS packages that use the main rosdep which specifies (3.0.x-1+ros4~lucid).